# How to create a backend for a custom theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, themes, theme-options

Let's assume that there are six different pages in a website.
Each page is different & only common part is header & footer.
So how will you create back end such that most of the website can be changed / edited by user?

So far what I am doing is creating six different pages. After that I am adding HTML directly into WYSIWYG for each page. This option works but it does not give full flexibility to the user. On the top of that, if the user deletes something, he can't get back to the previous stage. He has to copy all the HTML again.

Is there a better way to address this situation?

Comment: There must be at least 25 questions here about how to make dynamic pages, page "sections", page "blocks", etc. I've answered a few of them. Please try searching. Besides that, there are at least half a dozen different ways to do this. You are going to have to be more specific about your needs.

Comment: Can you please help me with few links. I did searched but doesn't seems to get what I want. And thanks for fixing my typo in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can create using page builders as well as using widgets or you can use custom post types and create page templates for different pages of your custom WordPress theme website.

Comment: The question is **how** to do that. Please be specific, add a reproducable example.